# Download file created by PHP without changing windows

Tags: php

I'm generating a file whenever a php script is run, which is downloaded in at the same time by the user (no copies are saved to the server).

Currently I'm redirecting a user from the file creation php script back to the original page.

I'd like to not redirect the user back to the original page but have them stay on the original page and the PHP script to still run and prompting them to save the custom created file.

I'm not entirely sure, but would be adding/changing something from the end of my current PHP script or simply changing my HTML link to it somehow?  I'm

My HTML

```
<a href="fileCreator.php">Download File</a>
```

My PHP

```
header("Content-type: text/txt");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.txt");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Location: [ORIGINAL PAGE]");
echo $txtFile;
```

Comment: Hey, please accept answers to the questions you have asked, so that anyone else who if facing the same problem will know which answer helped you.

Comment: I think it supposed to be text/plain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set a target on your link to an iframe (which you can set to be hidden), you can have the download prompt come up and your user will never have to leave the page on which they clicked the download link.

```
<a href="fileCreator.php" target="download_frame">Download File</a>
<iframe id="download_frame" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
header("Content-Type: $fileType");
header("Content-Length: $fileSize");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
echo $fileContent;
```

Then just link to this PHP file, it shouldn't make the user leave the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header("Content-type: application/force-download"); 
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
```

Comment: `application/force-download` doesn't exist in HTTP, the only reason it works is because browsers are smart enough to just download the file if they encounter unknown mimetype. Please stop copy pasting.